# Client rendering time

Tags: client

I know that in order to measure end-to-end response time for any application scenario, we need to compute: server time + network time + client time

While I know for sure, server and network time are impacted by load, I want to know if client time too is impacted by load??

If client rendering time isn't impacted by load then will it be appropriate, if we do a test with 100 users and measure server time with help of any performance testing tool (like HP LoadRunner, JMeter etc); then measure client rendering time with single user and finally present end-to-end time by adding client time to server time?

Any views on this will be appreciated.

Reagrds,

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a very old concept, termed a GUI Virtual User.   LoadRunner, and other classical tools such as SilkPerfomer, QALoad and Rational Performance tester, have always had the ability to run one or two graphical virtual users created with the functional automation test tools from the vendor in question to address the question of user "weight" of the GUI.

This capability went out of vogue for a while with the advent of the thin client web, but now that web clients are growing in thickness with complex client side code this question is being asked more often.

Don't worry about actual "rendering time," the time taken to draw the screen elements, since you cannot control that anyway.   It will vary from workstation to workstation depending upon what is running on the host and most development shops don't have a reconciliation path to Microsoft, Mozilla, Opera, Google or Apple to ask them to tune up the rendering on their browsers if someone finds a problem in the actual rendering engine of the browser.